# link static library (without -fPIC) to shared library on 64bit OS

Tags: c++, linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I write programm in c++, from which will be made shared library - and done it will be used by JNI. I have 3rd party library ( libexample.a ) and need to link it to shared library ( libshared.so ). The problem is, that I work on 64bit CentOS and -fPIC is needed to create shared lib, but 3rd party library wasnt compiled with -fPIC.

Until building I recive: 
`/usr/bin/ld: /home/tom/Project/src/libexample.a(SomeObject.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against 'someData' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Is it possible to make shared library in this situation? (I dont have source code of libexample.a ...)

Is there any workaround to make it work? Even ideas when I will have to write additional apps.

I hope that my question isn`t duplicate (more or less) because I spent long time at searching of possibilities.
Thanks, bez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there was not way to make any workaround. I had to write to 3rd party library developers to compile once again with `-fPIC`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`set_property(TARGET TheirLib PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)`

This will set the fPIC option on the 3rd party project.

[Source for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296756/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-in-cmake-to-add-the-fpic-compiler-option)