# How to correctly convert this Makefile to CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: unity-game-engine, makefile, cmake, unity3d-native-plugins

I am trying to write a `CMakeLists.txt` for my Unity3D NativeAudioSDK spatializer plugin (written in C++). An almost identical build configuration can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/keijiro/nativeaudioplugins/src/7d21219cbe7c3d85fbde1afe0036053515f4bed2/NativeCode/Makefile?fileviewer=file-view-default). The equivalent `Makefile` for my project looks like this:

```
SRCS=AudioPluginUtil.cpp \
Plugin_Spatializer.cpp \
hrtftable.cpp
OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=*.o)
OUTPUT=libAudioPluginDemo.so
CXXFLAGS=-I. -O2 -fPIC
LDFLAGS=-shared -rdynamic -fPIC
CXX=g++

all: $(OUTPUT)
clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUT) $(OBJS)

$(OUTPUT): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(OUTPUT) $(OBJS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

I want to use CMake for cross-platform development and buildfile generation. My current `CMakeLists.txt` works for Windows development and looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(DomeSpatializer)

if(WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
endif(WIN32)

file(GLOB DEPENDENCIES
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/externals/nativeaudioplugins/NativeCode/AudiopluginInterface.h"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/externals/nativeaudioplugins/NativeCode/AudioPluginUtil.h"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/externals/nativeaudioplugins/NativeCode/AudioPluginUtil.cpp"
)

add_library(DomeSpatializer SHARED "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/spatializer.cpp" ${DEPENDENCIES})

if(UNIX)
  target_link_options(DomeSpatializer PUBLIC "-rdynamic")
endif(UNIX)
```

On Linux, using the `Makefile`, everything works fine. However, the `CMakeLists.txt` generates a shared object file that Unity does not recognize as a spatializer plugin. I tried setting the linker flags (`-fPIC -shared -rdynamic`) using `target_linker_options()` or various variables such as `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` without success. Is there anything I am missing? How can i achieve the same correct build configuration with CMakeLists.txt? Any help is greatly appreciated at this point.

---

I am calling CMake in a `build.sh` script like this:

`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m64 -fPIC" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-m64 -fPIC"`

---

Versions of involved software:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS / Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
- cmake 3.14.0
- g++ 7.3.0
- Unity 2018.2.1f1 Personal (64bit)

---

My file structure looks like this:

```
.
│   build.sh
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   
├───externals
│   └───nativeaudioplugins            
│       └───NativeCode
│               AudioPluginInterface.h
│               AudioPluginUtil.cpp
│               AudioPluginUtil.h
│               hrtftable.cpp
│               Makefile
│               PluginList.h
│               Plugin_Spatializer.cpp
│
└───source
        spatializer.cpp
```

Note that `./source/spatializer.cpp` and `./externals/nativeaudioplugins/NativeCode/Plugins_Spatializer.cpp` are identical, but i want to use `spatializer.cpp` in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: You may use `make VERBOSE=1` for CMake-generated project to see exact command lines executed. Compare options in the linker command line with one you have in hand-written Makefile. In CMake analogue of `CXXFLAGS` is `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the ```VERBOSE=1``` hint, I am going to try that right now. The ```DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS``` are necessary because I generate both ```-m32``` and ```-m64``` in the ```build.sh```. Therefore I just added the ```-fPIC``` there. Is there any advantage of moving this flag into the ```CMakeLists.txt```?

Comment: @Tsyvarev like written in the question: I call CMake in my ```build.sh``` like this:

```cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m64 -fPIC" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-m64 -fPIC"```. I found that to be the easiest way to differentiate between x64 and x86 builds.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that `-fPIC` set in the calling script. BTW, [idiomatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296756/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-in-cmake-to-add-the-fpic-compiler-option) for set `-fPIC` flag in CMake is `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)`. And shared libraries has this flag set automatically.