# compiling a script employing lib2geom with cmake-js for use in N-API node.js addon

Tags: c++, node.js-addon, node-addon-api, n-api, cmake-js

I am attempting to make use of [lib2geom](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/lib2geom) in an Electron app.  I was able to write a script that employs the library to obtain an intersection of two paths and then wrap it with node-addon-api using examples from https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples.  I've hosted this attempt: [lib2geom-path-boolean-addon](https://github.com/justin-hackin/lib2geom-path-boolean-addon).

I'm having problems using cmake-js to build the script (I was successful building a non-addon script using CMake). As documented in the CMakeLists.txt file, I get the following error when attempting to run the install npm script:

```
relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZGVZN4Geom6chooseIdEET_jjE16pascals_triangle' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

and adopting the suggestion [here](https://github.com/cmake-js/cmake-js/issues/204#issuecomment-599498730) (now commented) did not remedy the issue.

I'm just learning C++ and CMake for this addon so it's hard to know where to start with debugging this issue.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.  I hope this can become a valuable resource for the community.

Comment: I fixed my problem by using the solution provided in this [SO accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297422/2780052)